# Execute function after addStateDidChangeListener

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to implement a way to detect on app start whether a certain value is nil, if so a specific VC shall be shown.

```
if value == 0 {
            let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "InitialViewController") as! InitialViewController
            self.window?.rootViewController = controller
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

I'm also calling following function in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: `Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in ...`, which listens to the auth user state.

It works fine, but only for a second - since the Firebase function needs its time to be executed, it changes the view again even if `value == 0`.

How can I call my desired if statement after the firebase function has made his first call?

Answer (score 0):

You have to either

1- Dim the window with a loading until that asynchronous method is called , then it's code will set the root vc

2- Do

```
if value != 0 { 
   // go to home
}
```

as `value = 0` means same initial vc so no need to re-set it

Comment: How do I implement the first option?

Comment: to make it simple create a splash vc and make it the initial vc in IB , and inside it's `viewDidLoad` add a `UIActivityIndicatorView` then after the function returns it will change that splash to either login/home